# Run a Linux GUI application as service accessible via web (VNC?)

Tags: linux, web-apps, remote-access, gui

We have a Linux GUI application (written mostly in Qt) and we need to create a web-accessible method of running it. That is, the application will be hosted on our server(s) and the users should be able to use an ordinary web browser to run it.

Does a software solution exist that provides this?

The proposed solution should work something like this:

- The user logs into a site, where he/she is presented with a way to a) create/run his/her own specific X11 session and connect to it, and b) upload/download his/her data files.
- Each user has his/her own X11 session, which will be closed after a certain amount of time of inactivity. This session is accessible via a web-based VNC client any time.
- We should be able to limit the CPU and memory resources per each user.
- The only thing the user is able to do while logged in is to run our application.
- This should work for both low and high DPI monitors on the user side.

Comment: VNC can be used as the actual remote desktop protocol. However, I don't think there is software that does what you're asking for out of the box, and you'll most likely have to implement that yourself, some kind of web app that handles authentication, talks to a central daemon that manages sessions, that daemon starts and stops user sessions as needed and starts a VNC server for each one of them, with a random port and password, and finally passes back the port + password to the web interface where a Javascript VNC client can seamlessly connect to it.